# Error using Page Object Model in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, test-automation-framework

I am trying to design an automation framework, using the page object model, I am new to automation. I am stuck at this point, could not solve it. Kindly help
I am getting Cannot invoke

> "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "this.driver" is null error

Base class:

```
package resources;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import pageObjects.userDetails;

public class base {
    public WebDriver driver;
    public Properties property;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public WebDriver initializeDriver() throws IOException {
        
        
        property = new Properties();
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("D:\\Automation-TestUni\\TestUni\\src\\main\\java\\resources\\data.properties");
        
        property.load(file);
        String BrowserName = property.getProperty("browser");
         
        if(BrowserName.equals("chrome")) 
        {
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\TestUni-Framework\\Framework\\chromedriver.exe");   
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            
        }
        else if(BrowserName.equals("firefox")) 
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        else if(BrowserName.equals("IE")) 
        {
            //Executes IE
        }
        
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return driver;
        
        
    }
public void user() throws IOException {
        
        
        driver.get("link");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        userDetails ud = new userDetails(driver);
        ud.getusername().sendKeys("xxxx");;
        ud.getpass().sendKeys("xxxx");
        ud.submit().click();
        
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("window.scroll(0,1000)");
        ud.agreed().click();
        
        ud.getUniLink().click();
        ud.portal().click();
        
    }

}
```

User details page object class:

```
package pageObjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class userDetails {
    
    public WebDriver driver;
    
    By username = By.name("user");
    By pass = By.name("pass");
    By submit = By.name("submit");
    By agreed = By.name("agreed");
    By Uni = By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/ul[1]/li[2]/a[1]");
    By portal = By.xpath("//a[@href='../../Key_Indicator/Criteria/Criteria.html#features-sec']");
    
    
    public userDetails(WebDriver driver) {
        
        this.driver=driver;
    }
    
    public WebElement getusername() 
    {
        
        return driver.findElement(username);
        
    }
    public WebElement getpass() 
    {
        
        return driver.findElement(pass);
        
    }
    public WebElement submit() 
    {
        
        return driver.findElement(submit);
    }
    public WebElement agreed() 
    {
        
        return driver.findElement(agreed);
    }
    public WebElement getUniLink() 
    {
        
        return driver.findElement(Uni);
        
    } 
    public WebElement portal() 
    {
        
        return driver.findElement(portal);
        
    } 

}
```

Curricular Aspects page object class:

```
package pageObjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class CurricularAspects {
    

    public WebDriver driver;
    
    By CA = By.cssSelector("div.home-sec:nth-child(5) div.overlay div.container div.row.text-center div.col-lg-12.col-md-12.col-sm-12 div.flexslider.set-flexi:nth-child(1) ul.slides.move-me > a.btn.btn-info.btn-ll:nth-child(2)");
    
    public CurricularAspects(WebDriver driver) {
        
        this.driver=driver;
    }
    
    public WebElement curricular() {
        
        return driver.findElement(CA);
    }

}
```

Test class :

```
package Automation.TestUni;



import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import pageObjects.CurricularAspects;
import resources.base;

public class Criteria_1 extends base{
    static WebDriver driver;
    

    @BeforeTest
    public void LoginCriteria1() throws IOException {
        
    
        base b = new base();
        b.initializeDriver();
        b.user();
        
        
    }
    
    @Test
    public void curricular() throws InterruptedException {
        
        
        CurricularAspects ca = new CurricularAspects(driver);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        ca.curricular().click();
        
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `Criteria_1`  extends `base`, why you are instantiating `base` class? Your application needs advance code review. Why you are defining a static driver in your test class is another question...

Anyway you should use `ITestContext` to store driver in the context and then use that context with `getCTX` method with annotation `@BeforeClass` in the test class in order to get the value of the `driver` and use it in the factory page.

Comment: Thank you. 
It worked, removed base class instantiation.